# building static version of Poco C++ libraries

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

can any body guide us on how to build static version of the Poco C++ libraries ?

Comment: please add a few deatils about your platform, IDE,...

Comment: In my opinion this question is *highly* constructive

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you use you use autotools to build Poco, run `./configure` with the `--static` flag.

```
$ ./configure --static
```

See `./configure --help` for a full list of flags.

Comment: is there a way to get it to build only release (non debug) libraries?

Comment: Setting the `DEFAULT_TARGET` does not work. So I changed the lines that set the `DEFAULT_TARGET` as `all_shared`, `all_static` to `shared_release` and `static_release` in `build/rules/global`.
That seems to work.